# Split multiple lines and input them in separate row in a database

Tags: php, mysql, insert, rows

I am trying to create a php script that inputs the HTTP links pasted into a textarea into a separated row in a database. More exactly:

First page is where the textarea `(name=textarea-linkfield)` is, links are going to be pasted here

```
http://www.stackoverflow.com
http://www.yahoo.com
....
http://google.com
```

The links are being carried over into the php script with `$linkfield=$_POST['textarea-linkfield'];` and I would like the links to be inserted into the database, each http link per row. Database name: site, table name plow, columns: id, url, ...

L.E. I tried just as proof of concept:

```
$linkfield=$_POST['textarea-linkfield'];
$strip=explode("\n",$linkfield);
echo $strip[1];
```

but I get 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

L.E.2

The answer:

```
// Split the string into pieces
$pieces = explode("\n", str_replace(array("\n", "\r\n"), "\n", trim($linkfield)));

// Build the top of the INSERT query
$sql = "INSERT INTO `plow`(`url`) VALUES\n";

// Build the rest of the ;INSERT query by re-assembling the
// pieces.
$sql .= "('";
$sql .= implode("'), ('", $pieces);
$sql .= "')"; 
mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_close();
```

Thanks to all for their help.
Chris.

Comment: An `explode()` on `"\n"` should work, try it, and if you don't succeed come back with some code of your best effort.

Comment: Is the textarea included in a form that you are submitting?

Comment: Take a look at PHP's error reporting functionality to see if you can squeeze a bit more information out of the error: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Yes. Regular form, nothing fancy.

Comment: If I do $strip=nl2br($linkfield); echo $strip; The links are being displayed 1 per row, but not sure how to link every one of them from there to a variable and insert it in the databse.

Comment: Keep in mind that in order to pull out a field from $_POST, you need to set name="textarea-linkfield", not id. The code you've got there should work. Personally I would also iterate over the array and run a trim() on each element before inserting it into the data ... accidental whitespace is evil

Comment: My mistake, I was using name for the text area. I updated the question. Thanks,C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your os a newline can be "\n", "\r\n" or "\r".

Give this a shot:

```
$strip=explode("<br>", nl2br($linkfield));
```

or maybe safer:

```
$strip=explode("\n", str_replace(array("\n", "\r\n"), "\n", $linkfield));
```

Comment: Linux environment and is working with the second line of code, now I need to come up with the code to insert it into the database. Thanks PMV.

Comment: foreach ($strip as $website) {
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (url) VALUES ('$website')");
}

Answer (score 0):

use preg_match to find each URL and add it to the database.
Example 3 on this page should do the trick: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php
this way you can enter URLs without having to use a new line.
if you're only using URLs, then you could also add a delimeter after each URL i.e. a comma (which isnt used in a URL) to explode them with using the explode() idea in the comment.

Comment: I would like to come up with a script that can work without me adding commas or any other delimiter and the links need to be inputted into the textarea into a new line. Thanks, Chris.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your question, answered:
http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/850719-extracting-individual-lines-multiline-text-box-processing

Comment: Thanks Ted, indeed that was the answer. I pasted the answer at the bottom of the question for others to use. Thanks all for your help. Good night, Chris.